# Excel Pivot Table with a macro

Tags: vba, excel, pivot-table

I recorded a macro that generated a very simple pivot table. When I played the macro back I get an error in the `PivotTable`.

I get:

> Invalid procedure call or argument

So I went back and put single quotes around the `SourceData` and `TableDestination`.  Now I get a pivot table but only with the total.  It should give me the count of all the occurrences of the items in Column A.

Here's the code

```
 Sub testpivot()
'
' testpivot Macro
'
ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= _
    "'GF Response Detail R'!R1C1:R65536C1", Version:= _
    xlPivotTableVersion10).CreatePivotTable TableDestination:= _
    "'GF Response Detail R'!R2C10", TableName:="PivotTable1", _
    DefaultVersion:=xlPivotTableVersion10
Sheets("GF Response Detail R").Select
Cells(2, 7).Select
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Region")
    .Orientation = xlRowField
    .Position = 1
End With
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").AddDataField ActiveSheet.PivotTables( _
    "PivotTable1").PivotFields("Region"), "Count of Region", xlCount
    ActiveWorkbook.ShowPivotTableFieldList = False

End Sub
```

Comment: Are you wanting to create a new pivot table every time? Because you can create a macro that just updates the pivot table that you currently have in your workbook. With this current setup you will only be using the data from the defined parameters. So it will only be creating a pivot based on inputs from A1:A65536 so if you have say 66K rows next time the macro will only be based off of the original ~65k you originally defined.

Comment: yes. It's a new report every month. So we'll run the macro on a new document every time.

Answer (score 2):

You want to remove the Pivot Table from the worksheet. Before you run the macro.

Answer (score 1):

The code below will check first if there's a "PivotTable1" in the sheet, and if it does it will delete it.

Afterwards, it will create a new `PivotTable` on "GF Response Detail R" sheet, with the updated data in Column "A".

**Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub testpivot()

' testpivot Macro
Dim PivTbl      As PivotTable
Dim PivCache    As PivotCache
Dim DataSht     As Worksheet
Dim lastRow     As Long
Dim SrcRng      As Range
Dim SrcData     As String

' set the Pivot Data
Set DataSht = Worksheets("GF Response Detail R")    
With DataSht
    lastRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row '<-- get last row in Column A

    Set SrcRng = .Range("A1:A" & lastRow) '<-- set dynamic Pivot Range
    SrcData = SrcRng.Address(True, True, xlA1, xlExternal) '<-- get the Range Address, including sheet's name
End With    

'-- first check if there's a "PivotTable1" in sheet >> if Yes, Delete it
For Each PivTbl In DataSht.PivotTables
    If PivTbl.Name = "PivotTable1" Then
        DataSht.Range(PivTbl.TableRange2.Address).Delete Shift:=xlUp
        Exit For
    End If
Next PivTbl

' set the Pivot Cache
'Set PivCache = ThisWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=SrcData)

' Option 2: set the Pivot Cache
Set PivCache = ThisWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=SrcRng)

' Option 3: set the Pivot Cache
Set PivCache = ThisWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=SrcData, Version:=xlPivotTableVersion15)

' create a new Pivot Table in "EXP Pivot" sheet, start from Cell A1
Set PivTbl = DataSht.PivotTables.Add(PivotCache:=PivCache, TableDestination:=DataSht.Range("J2"), TableName:="PivotTable1")

With PivTbl
    With .PivotFields("Region")
        .Orientation = xlRowField
        .Position = 1
    End With

    .AddDataField .PivotFields("Region"), "Count of Region", xlCount
    ActiveWorkbook.ShowPivotTableFieldList = False
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: I'm getting 'Invalid procedure call or argument' on the Set PivTbl =

Comment: @MattWiner try the edited code (changed the `PivCache` line)

Comment: I tried a brand new clean sheet with just the column A data in it. Still getting 'Invalid Procedure' on the PivTble line

Comment: @MattWiner What Excel version are you running ? Add `Debug.Print PivCache.SourceData` before the `Set PivTbl` line, what are you getting in the immediate window ?

Comment: Excel 2013. from debug.print `'GF Response Detail R'!R1C1:R151C1`

Comment: @MattWiner the **Option 3**, strange, since they all work for me

Comment: I got the same results as Matt but I was able to get the solution that I posted to work.

Comment: @BWMustang13 I wonder why, I have been running this code for months now, on different tools I'm using at works  (reports) and many posts here on SO. I wonder...

Answer (score 0):

Here try this. It is a slight variation of what @Shai Rado was suggesting.

```
Sub RegionMacro()

Dim DSheet As Worksheet
Dim PCache As PivotCache
Dim PTable As PivotTable
Dim PRange As Range
Dim LastRow As Long

'define the sheet, last row, and pivot table range
Set DSheet = Worksheets("GF Response Detail R")
LastRow = DSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
Set PRange = DSheet.Range("A1:A" & LastRow)

'get address of range
sData = PRange.Address(False, True)

'check to see if the table already exist and delete it if it does
For Each PTable In DSheet.PivotTables
    If PTable.Name = "RegionCountTable" Then
        DSheet.Range(PTable.TableRange2.Address).Delete Shift:=xlUp
        Exit For
    End If
Next PTable

'define the pivot cache
Set PCache = ThisWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=PRange)

'insert a blank pivot table into cell G2 and call it "RegionCountTable"
Set PTable = PCache.CreatePivotTable(TableDestination:=DSheet.Cells(2, 7), TableName:="RegionCountTable")

'insert row fields
With PTable

    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("RegionCountTable").PivotFields("Region")
     .Orientation = xlRowField
     .Position = 1
    End With

    'create a count for the region
    .AddDataField .PivotFields("Region"), "Count of Region", xlCount
    ActiveWorkbook.ShowPivotTableFieldList = False
End With


End Sub
```

Comment: Once you've defined `Set PTable` and have `With PTable`, you don't need `With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("RegionCountTable").PivotFields("Region")` just use `.PivotFields("Region")`

Comment: I thank you all for you help.  Unfortunately not making any progress. Not sure if it's my version of Excel or something that I'm doing totally wrong. I still get `Invalid procedure call or argument`

Comment: The only way I get it to run so far is by adding a new sheet (which I'd be ok with), setting it as the active sheet.  Then setting the `TableDestination:=""` but then the result is only the total `"Count of Region" "148"`

Comment: When you run my code what line do you get the error for?

Comment: I am not sure how you are getting that error. the only two causes are An argument probably exceeds the range of permitted values and if an attempt is made to call a procedure that isn't valid on the current platform (Mac vs PC). The arguments seem to be within the parameters. Are you on a Mac or PC?

Comment: @BWMustang13 PC